# Logging into SF Community after IDP authentication

Tags: community

How do I login to the Salesforce community after the IDP authentication is completed?

We are trying to build the entire login flow in Salesforce with calls to IDP to validate the user including MFA (via REST calls). At the end of this whole process, once the IDP gives the green light, how do I enable the user to login to Salesforce community. `

`I see that the Site.login(username, password, startUrl) only accepts passwords. Is there any other way for me to login once the IDP completes the authentication and respond back to Salesforce.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear if IdP is external to Salesforce..but if so, redirect the user to the IdP and tell the IdP to launch Salesforce.

Comment: Yes the IDP is external to Salesforce. But as I said, the login UX is fully managed by Salesforce so redirecting to IDP is not an option here. Salesforce will only provide the UI for this login flow while authentication is perfomed at IDP via API calls. Hope this clears.